# $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

I'm trying to show that 
$T := \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ for some $d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now I know that as $T$ is a tensor product, there exists a bilinear map $t : \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow T$ such that for all Abelian groups $A$ and all bilinear maps $b : \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A$, there exists a unique $\tilde{b} : T \rightarrow A$ such that $b = \tilde{b} \circ t$. This is by definition of the tensor product.

I first note that for $d := \text{gcd}(m,n)$, the map

$$b :\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}, (x \mod m, y \mod n) \mapsto xy \mod d$$

is a well-defined bilinear map. This then gives us our unique $\tilde{b}$.

Now *if it were true* that $(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}, b)$ is also a tensor product, we would obtain a map $\tilde{t}$ such that $\tilde{b} = \tilde{t}^{-1}$, hence giving a group isomorphism $T \tilde{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$.

To prove this, I would have to show that for every Abelian group $A$ and every bilinear map $a : \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A$, there exists a unique map $\tilde{t}: \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A$ such that $a = \tilde{t} \circ b$. 
Unfortunately I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: Hint: if $d = am + bn$ then $d \otimes 1 = a(m \otimes 1) + b(1 \otimes n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like a more algebraic approach, consider the map 
$$
f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z,\; a \mapsto a \otimes 1.
$$
This is clearly surjective, so we must have 
$$
\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z / \ker f.
$$
Now all that is left is to show that $\ker f$ is of the form $d \mathbb Z$. In particular if $a \in (m,n)$ then there are $k,\ell$ such that $a = km + \ell n$. Then 
$$
a \otimes 1 = km \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \ell n = 0 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes 0 = 0.
$$
This shows $(m,n) \subset \ker f$. 
The converse is also true, so we are done.

**Big edit**

My "proof" essentially sidesteps using the universal property of the tensor product, and instead pushes it to the last step which I skip. I have tried to make this step rigorous but fail to do this in a nice way. So let us instead use your method.

Suppose everything in your post. In particular we have the map $a : \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z \to A$. We must show that there exists a unique $\Bbb Z$-linear map $a' : \Bbb Z / d \Bbb Z \to A$ such that $a'\circ b = a$.

The tough part (I guess) is to find the map $a'$ and to recognize that $d = \gcd(m,n)$.

So let $d = \gcd(m,n)$ and define the map
$$
a' : \Bbb Z / d \Bbb Z \to A,\; x \mapsto a(x,1).
$$
One then shows that this map is well-defined, $\Bbb Z$-linear, satisfies $a'\circ b = a$ and unique.

Assume first that $a'$ is well-defined.
The $\Bbb Z$-linearity follows immediately from the $\Bbb Z$-bilinearity of $a$.
One checks that $a'\circ b(x,y) = a'(xy) = a(xy, 1) = y \cdot a(x,1) = a(x,y)$. Uniqueness can also easily be checked.

So what remains to be shown is well-definedness. Suppose $x \equiv y \mod d$, then $x - y = z \cdot d$ some $d$-multiple. Since $d = \gcd(m,n)$ there are $k,\ell$ integers such that $d = km + \ell n$. Now
$$
a'(x) - a'(y) = a(x,1) - a(y,1) = a(x - y,1)\\ = a(zd,1) = a(zkm + z \ell n,1) = a(zkm,1) + a(1,z \ell n) = a(0,1) + a(1,0) = 0.
$$
So $a$ is well-defined and we are done.

Comment: How does the universal property of tensor products manifest itself here?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman I see now that my proof tries to sidestep using the universality of the tensor product, and that it is actually hidden in the last step that I omitted (and is, on second thought, not so trivial).

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman I have tried to fix the problem by using the universality to give a complete proof.

Comment: I commend you sir! You look to be a magnificent contributor. I did change a little thing though (in showing $a = a' \circ b$), hope you agree. Haven't figured uniqueness (my weakness) out yet by the way.

Comment: Perfect, I was a little too rushed there I think.
For uniqueness, I would suppose we have another map $a''$ that is also $a$ after composition with $b$. Then $a'' \circ b(x,y) = a(x,y) = a' \circ b(x,y)$. Since the map $b$ is a surjection this is enough to show that $a'' = a'$.

Comment: Fantastic, taking $A = T$ and $a = t$ now, we find that $a' \circ \tilde{b} = \text{id}_T$. But then $(\tilde{b} \circ a') \circ \tilde{b} = \tilde{b} \circ (a' \circ \tilde{b}) =  \tilde{b} \circ \text{id}_T = \tilde{b}$, so $\tilde{b} \circ a' = \text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}}$, so $\tilde{b} = a'^{-1}$, and we have our desired group isomorphism. :)